# Configuration Error while running the project

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<configuration>
   <configSections>
     <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
      <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit 
   <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth"  type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
```

Hi i am getting the above error when i tried to run my project in MVC4.
Please let me know what should i do resolve this error.

Comment: Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for entityFramework: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Maybe check in your bin folder, does it have such dll?

Comment: Entityframework dll is there in bin folder and entityframework reference with version 6.0.0.0 is also there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below suggestion would work (highlighted with **). Please let me know the result.

```
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=**6.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Please help to mark the post as answer.Maybe this post would be useful for others in the future.